# How to use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to retrieve Decimal(4,2)

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` to retrieve a `Decimal(4,2)` value from the DB. Had it been an `int` value, I could've done `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForInt()` but I dont find a similar function for retrieving a Decimal. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `queryForObject` method of the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`

```
// Thanks to  Mark Rotteveel
BigDecimal result = (BigDecimal)template.queryForObject("select 1.0 from dual", new HashMap(), java.lang.BigDecimal.class);
```

Comment: JDBC maps Decimal and Numeric to `BigDecimal` (see Appendix B of the JDBC 4.1 specification) + there is no class called `java.lang.Decimal` in Java, and Number is an abstract class

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I think it's `java.math` instead of `java.lang`. It worked just fine. Thanks :)